# How to use query paramaters for spotify api using node.js?

Tags: node.js, spotify, query-string, bad-request

```
    var queryparam = "track:godsplan%20artist:drake&type=track&market=US&limit=10";

    app.get('/get_track', function(req,res){

        var options = {
            url:"https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?"+queryparam,
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
            json: true
         }

    request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {

        if(!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
          console.log(body);
        }
        else{
            console.log(error);
            console.log(response.statusCode);
        }
    res.redirect('/#'); 
 });  

});
```

here is what I have and i am trying to get god's plan by drake to appear on my console when I run the server on local host and my access_token works but whenever i run the `"/get_track"` i get a bad request error, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

what is that module "request" ?
(http, request-promise, request)

although I suppose that your request is simply not correctly formed
you need to try:

```
var queryparam = "q=track:godsplan%20artist:drake&type=track&market=US&limit=10";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your missing `q=`

`var queryparam = "q=track:godsplan%20artist:drake&type=track&market=US&limit=10";`

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search/search/#request-parameters